# efficiently view N most recently edited files in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a massive folder of files, `bigfolder`. I want to view the N most recently modified files. For example, N could be 10. I use `ls -rlta bigfolder` to view the most recently edited files, but this is undesirable because it takes a long time. With this method, I can filter the output to view the N most recently edited files, `ls -rlta bigfolder | tail -n 10`. Is there a faster way I can view the 10 most recently edited files?

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: If you're using a consistent tool to edit the files, you might want to see if that tool caches the info for you.  eg, in vim, use `:filter` with `:oldfiles` or `:browse`.

Comment: My files have been generated by a simple python script. I did not think to add a log of edited files. I'll do that in the future, thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 2):

Shooting blindly:

`ls` without colours and without `-l`:

```
ls -t -1 --color=never | head -n 10 | xargs -I {} ls -l {}
```

Maybe `find` if you don't care that they are really the latest N

```
find . -cmin -1
```

`-cmin` - File's status was last changed n minutes ago.